# Is it possible to iterate over an id string in the following manner?

Tags: android

```
 for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
            {
            String my_id="Ezequiel_1_"+i;
        final TextView modelTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_id);
        modelTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                the_controller.buttonController(v);
            }
        });
    }
```

I arranged my ids in the previous manner and I don't want to set the method one by one. Is it possible to iterate like that?

Comment: Not exactly but there is a method to obtain id from string ... how? use search, question was asked bazillion times ... off-topic comment it would be better to not store data in layout but fx in database and use ListView/RecyclerView

Comment: Hey hey stop! I don't know what some peoples are doing by visiting this thread they are not even reading the question this guy has asked. That's a good question though. But some peoples are visiting this thread and simply down voting it. Its not good. Please up vote him. That's still good question though.

Comment: It looks like I am being downvoted because of the christian content of my thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, because strings aren't ids.  There's two ways to do what you want though:

1)Data based

```
int textViewIds[] = [R.id.Ezequiel_1_1, R.id.Ezequiel_1_2, R.id.Ezequiel_1_3,...]
for(int id: textViewIds) {
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id);
   ...
}
```

2)Name based

```
for(int i=0; i<numView, i++) {
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("Ezequiel_1_"+i, "id", 
       context.getPackageName());
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id);
   ...
}
```

I prefer method 1 as it gives you clearer code and protection against off by 1 errors (they won't compile).

Comment: what's the name of the data structure in the first piece of code?

Comment: Sorry in the first it's just an array. I was missing the square brackets